# how to sum the elements specified by a cell in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a big matrix M (nxm). I am going to sum some elements which are specified by index stored in vector as cell elements. There are many groups of indices so the cell has more than one element. For example

```
M = rand(2103, 2030);
index{1} = [1 3 2 4 53 5 23 3];
index{2} = [2 3 1 3 23 10234 2032];
% ...
index{2032} = ...;
```

I am going to sum up all elements at index{1}, sum up all elements at index{2} ..., now I am using a loop

```
sums = zeros(1, 2032);
for n=1:2032
  sums(n) = sum(M(index{n}));
end
```

I am wondering if there is any way to use one-line command instead of a loop to do that. Using a loop is pretty slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a classic use of `cellfun`

```
sums = cellfun(@(idx) sum(M(idx)), index);
```

**EDIT:** here is a benchmarking for a large case that shows that this approach is slightly slower than a for loop but faster than Eitan T's method

```
M = rand(2103, 2030);
index = cell(1, 2032);
index{1} = [1 3 2 4 53 5 23 3];
index{2} = [2 3 1 3 23 10234 2032];

for n=3:2032
    index{n} = randi(numel(M), 1, randi(10000));
end

N = 1e1;
sums = zeros(1, 2032);
tic
for kk = 1:N
    for n=1:2032
        sums(n) = sum(M(index{n}));
    end
end
toc

tic
for kk = 1:N
    sums = cellfun(@(idx) sum(M(idx)), index);
end
toc

tic
for kk = 1:N
    sums = cumsum(M([index{:}]));
    sums = diff([0, sums(cumsum(cellfun('length', index)))]);
end
toc
```

results in

```
Elapsed time is 2.072292 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.139882 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.669894 seconds.
```

Comment: This is neater, but I doubt it is faster. I suggest bench-marking it against the loop if efficiency is your main concern.

Comment: @EitanT I couldn't see that order of magnitude you are referring to. See the benchmarking in my edit.

Comment: That's because you're running it for an `index` containing only two cells. I'll add my own benchmarking code.

Comment: @EitanT No I'm not, there is a for loop to populate the index cell array in line 6-8 of the code.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Ah, you're right, I've missed that. So, what version of MATLAB are you running?

Comment: @EitanT These numbers are from R2011b and I see a similar trend in R2013a: 2.145491 / 2.255976 / 2.815689

Comment: @EitanT That is because in your benchmark you are limiting the size of arrays in `index` to 10 elements, while I'm allowing it to grow as large as 10000 elements. When I run your benchmark with arrays of length 10000 and N=1 I get 2.072292 / 2.139882 / 2.669894.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia After playing around with array sizes, I see that the loop/cellfun solutions start to outperform around ~2000 elements per each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not as elegant as a `cellfun` one-liner, but runs more than an order of magnitude faster:

```
sums = cumsum(M([index{:}]));
sums = diff([0, sums(cumsum(cellfun('length', index)))]);
```

It even runs approximately 4 or 5 times faster than a JIT-accelerated loop for large inputs. Note that when each cell in `index` contains a vector with more than ~2000 elements, the performance of this approach begins to deteriorate in comparison with a loop (and `cellfun`).

#### Benchmark

```
M = rand(2103, 2030);
I = ceil(numel(M) * rand(2032, 10));
index = mat2cell(I, ones(size(I, 1), 1), size(I, 2));
N = 100;

tic
for k = 1:N
    sums = zeros(1, numel(index));
    for n = 1:numel(sums)
        sums(n) = sum(M(index{n}));
    end
end
toc

tic
for k = 1:N
    sums = cellfun(@(idx) sum(M(idx)), index);
end
toc

tic
for k = 1:N
    sums = cumsum(M([index{:}]));
    sums2 = diff([0, sums(cumsum(cellfun('length', index)))]);
end
toc
```

When executing this in MATLAB 2012a (Windows Server 2008 R2 running on a 2.27GHz 16-core Intel Xeon processor), I got:

```
Elapsed time is 0.579783 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.789809 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.111455 seconds.
```

Comment: Would you please show us the benchamrking code? I find your code slower

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Added a comment based on our latest findings :)

Comment: Thanks! It's always interesting to see how different approaches behave when the data gets big.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Yes, and I'm also pleased to see that `cellfun` is not so bad in recent versions of MATLAB.